# How to use volume gp3 in storage class on EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, devops, amazon-eks

I'm converting volume gp2 to volume gp3 for EKS but getting this error.
***Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp3": invalid AWS VolumeType "gp3"***
This is my config.

StorageClass

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: gp3
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  type: gp3
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-pvc
  name: test-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: gp3
```

When I type `kubectl describe pvc/test`. This is response:

```
Name:          test-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  gp3
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=test-pvc
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                 ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  58s (x9 over 4m35s)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp3": invalid AWS VolumeType "gp3"
```

I'm using Kubernetes version 1.18.
Can someone help me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved your problem (Did the @gohm'c 's answer help you)?

Comment: Can you give your solution?
Thanks!

Comment: AWS released the instruction of migrating EKS from gp2 to gp3 EBS volumes

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/migrating-amazon-eks-clusters-from-gp2-to-gp3-ebs-volumes/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to use volume `gp3` in storage class on EKS.

1. First, you need to install `Amazon EBS CSI driver` with offical instruction [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html).
2. The next, you need to create the storage class `ebs-sc` after `Amazon EBS CSI driver` is installed, example:

---

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  type: gp3
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
EOF
```

So, you can use volume `gp3` in storage class on EKS.
You can check by deploying resources:

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-gp3-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app-gp3-in-tree
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: persistent-storage
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumes:
  - name: persistent-storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: ebs-gp3-claim
EOF
```

Detailed documentation on Migrating Amazon EKS clusters from gp2 to gp3 EBS volumes: https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/containers/migrating-amazon-eks-clusters-from-gp2-to-gp3-ebs-volumes/

References: [Persistent Storage in EKS failing to provision volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290796/persistent-storage-in-eks-failing-to-provision-volume)

Answer (score 7):

The default k8s storage driver support up to gp2 only. To use gp3 you need to install AWS EBS CSI driver. Here's the official [instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html) to install the driver.

Comment: another good resource https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/install.md